# Not found StoryBoarding Tab in PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2013

Somehow, I lost the storyboarding tab in PowerPoint. How can I recover it? thanks.

I am using both PowerPoint2010, and PowerPoint2013

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it by going to

**Powerpoint Options > Add-Ins**

There I noticed that the **Team Foundation Add-In** was disabled. When I enabled it, the Storyboard ribbon showed up.

I'm using Office 2013 with VS 2013 Update 4.

Good Luck with your fix.

Comment: I don't have that Team Foundation Add-In. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You need a particular edition of Visual Studio installed (e.g. [Storyboard your ideas using PowerPoint - microsoft.com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409276.aspx)).

Do you have it installed?

Comment: I have VS Ultimate 2013 installed, and already played around with the StoryBoarding Tab in PowerPoint, but now I lost it, and don't know how to recover this tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have visual studio 2019 and Power point 2016 but the story board is missing until I setup TFS Standalone Office Integration installer from link
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832491&clcid=0x409

Below Microsoft answer form link
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-get-storyboarding-option-on-my/f2411483-de28-475d-a2bc-5f9ebe907da2?tab=AllReplies#tabs

[image]